# Can Views Bulk Operation be used to re-index specific nodes

Tags: search, views

Can the Views Bulk Operations module be used to reindex nodes that fulfill some criteria (e.g. nodes of specific type)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't deal with that for a few time but since I found the answer my self I thought about posting that here in the hope that someone finds it useful. I dug into [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) and into the [Search API devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_devel), copied and modified some code.

For this to work we need to create a custom module and put in the module the following:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_action_info
 */
function MY_MODULE_api_action_info() {
  /**
   * Defines an array of actions to be performed on nodes
   */
  return array(
      'MY_MODULE_api_reindex' => array(
          'type' => 'node',
          'label' => t('Reindex node'),
          'behavior' => array('changes_property'),
          'configurable' => FALSE,
          'vbo_configurable' => FALSE,
          'triggers' => array('any'),
      ),
  );
}

function MY_MODULE_api_reindex(&$node, $context) {
  /**
   * function to implement the action defined above (see the key of the array
   * returned in vbo_search_api_action_info()
   */
  //copied the code from the search_api_devel module
  //load all indexes
  $indexes = search_api_index_load_multiple(FALSE);
  foreach ($indexes as $index) {
      if ($index->enabled) {
        search_api_index_specific_items($index, array($node->nid));
      }
    }  
}
```

There might be a better way to go around this problem. For example the code now loads the index for each visited node, whereas `Search API` supports indexing an array of `nids`. So potentially we could gather all nids and then submit to Search API